# How should I create a URL such /api/resource/identifier/resource/identifier

Tags: node.js, rest

I have a page with categories and page with goods for each category. How should I divide my api endpoints?

is that correct to use something like this:

'/api/categories'

'/api/categories/:categoryId'

'/api/categories/:categoryId/goods'

'/api/categories/:categoryId/goods/:itemId'

or should I use structure like:

'/api/categories'

'/api/categories/:categoryId'

'/api/goods'

'/api/goods/:itemId'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both answers are correct. There is usually no clear answer to questions like that. You can use one style of URLs, you can use the other style, or you can even use both with either the same resources available with two URL or with redirects.

The style of `/api/categories/:categoryId/goods/:itemId` has an advantage of nice hierarchy and more information in the URL itself.

But the style of `/api/goods/:itemId` has an advantage of being able to move goods between categories more easily, or even supporting multiple categories per item or adding tags in the future etc.

This is really something that you have to decide yourself, not only basing your decision on what URL seems better in itself but also considering your particular usage of the API that you're developing - like e.g. how likely it is to change categories, or how likely it is to access the goods without knowing the categories.

I recommend reading the tutorials about API design that were published by Stormpath. See:

- https://stormpath.com/blog/fundamentals-rest-api-design

I particularly recommend watching the talks by Les Hazlewood that you can find on the Stormpath website, because he explains a lot of subtle topics like that.